# Mapreduce usage

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've constructed a great map reduce and my data is coming out perfectly. The only question I have is that the map reduce create the collection every time the page is loaded, across every user. Is this the normal usage for a map reduce or should I be using cron to run it like once a day in the background or some other way of generating the content other then loading it every time.

Comment: What driver are you using for what programming language?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you **need** different results per request? Could you create a "totals" collection that could be used. Your question is too broad for any definitive answer. Anything else is just speculation unless you can provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual use-case for MapReduce is to run it as a background job, either to create a report or to cache aggregated and/or transformed data for later queries. So the default behavior is to write the data into a new collection.

But MapReduce also has an option to give you the output directly. When you execute a MapReduce command in the mongo shell, you do this by passing an object `{ inline: 1 }` as `out:` parameter. Here is an example:

```
db.runCommand(
           {
             mapReduce: 'source_collection',
             map: mapFunction,
             reduce: reduceFunction,
             out: { inline: 1 }
           }
```

You didn't say what database driver you are using, so the only advise one can give you is to refer to its documentation to find out if and how it exposes this functionality.

Keep in mind that an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) can cover all but the most obscure use-cases for inline MapReduce with usually superior performance and often much more readable code.